# Point between left and right limits of a CDF

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, economics

This is from the Chapter 15 text of Gourieroux and Monfort's Statistics and Econometric Models II:

**Set Up**: Suppose that there are 2 possible parameter values $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ from which there are 2 density functions $l_{\theta_0}(y)$ and $l_{\theta_1}(y)$ on the data. Define
$$
F(k)=P_{\theta_0}\left(\frac{l_{\theta_1}(Y)}{l_{\theta_0}(Y)}\leq k\right).
$$
Then, $F$ is right continuous, increasing, and $\lim_{k\to+\infty}F(k)=1$.

**Question:** If $F(k-)$ means $\lim_{x\uparrow k}F(x)$, why is it that: given any $\alpha\in(0,1)$, there exists a real number $k_0$ satisfying $F(k_0-)\leq\alpha\leq F(k_0)$?

This actually seems be a general property of Càdlàg functions. Very appreciative if someone could show me or point me to some proof. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't hold in general, you need to use the facts that $\lim_{k \to \infty}F(k) = 1$ and $F(0) = 0$. It does hold in general for distribution functions however. The following is adapted from Billingsley's **Probability and Measure**:

Define the quantile function to be 
$$
  \phi(u)
= \inf\{x \mid u \leq F(x) \}, \ \ \ u \in (0,1).
$$
Since $F$ is non-decreasing $\{x \mid u \leq F(x) \}$ is an interval stretching to $\infty$, and since $F$ is right-continuous the interval is closed on the left. So for $u \in (0,1)$ 
$$
  \{x \mid u \leq F(x) \}
= [\phi(u),\infty).
$$
This means that $\phi(u) \leq x$ if and only if $u \leq F(x)$.

So for $\alpha \in (0,1)$, let $k_0 = \phi(\alpha)$. Then $\alpha \leq F(k_0)$. Let $x_n$ be a sequence satisfying $x_n \uparrow k_0$. By the fact that $F$ has limits on the left and is non-decreasing,
$\lim_{x \to k_0}F(x) = F(k_0^-) \leq \alpha$

P.S. be cool to those North Koreans.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for pointing me to Billingsley! I cannot be the real Kim, or can I?

Comment: @KimJongUn haha, no problem, and I would be impressed if you were!

Answer (score 0):

Because $F$ is increasing and tends to $1$, given any $\alpha \in (0,1)$ there exists an $a \in  \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(a) \geq \alpha$. This shows that the set $A:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : F(x) \geq \alpha \} $ is nonempty. It is obviously bounded below because $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)= 0$. So we can set $k_0:= \inf A.$

But then $$ F(x) \leq \alpha \quad \forall x < k_0. $$

Taking limits as $x \uparrow k_0$ in the above inequality implies that $F(k_0-) \leq \alpha$.

**NB** We have used all the properties of the distribution function $F$ in the above. So we can conclude that this is a general property of *distribution functions*.

The same proof as above does however supply the following result:

Let $F$ be any *increasing* cadlag function. Then we can define $\alpha_{-}:= \lim{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)$ and  $\alpha_{+}:= \lim{x \rightarrow \infty}F(x)$, where we may have $\alpha_{\pm} = \pm \infty$ respectively. Then

$$ \forall \alpha \in (\alpha_{-}, \alpha_{+}) \quad \exists k_0 \in \mathbb{R} \quad \textrm{such that} \quad F(k_0-) \leq \alpha \leq F(k_0). $$

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. You answered the question, but I selected Rookatu's response for it arrived earlier. I will upvote this answer once I have enough reputation. Goodnight!

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know :)